# In Java, how would I get this countLines method to count a line without a newline character?

Tags: java

The following code counts the lines in a text file, but it doesn't count them if there is a line without a newline  (  `'\n'`  ) character :

```
public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));


try {
    byte[] c = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    int readChars = 0;
    boolean empty = true;
    while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
        empty = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
            if (c[i] == '\n'   /*  || c[i] != null  */ ) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
} finally {
    is.close();
}
```

When I tried adding in the code  `c[i] != null`  into the if-condition, it gave this error :

> NewParentClass.java:72: error: incomparable types: byte and ''
>
> ```
>     if (c[i] == '\n'    || c[i] != null  ) {
> ```

Comment: If you don't *have* to code it, I would suggest: `return Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).count();`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using your `empty` flag correctly. Instead of initializing it to `false` ahead of the nested loop, you need to set it to `true` when the character is `'\n'` and to `false` when it's not:

```
boolean empty = true;
while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
        if (c[i] == '\n') {
            ++count;
            empty = true;
        } else {
            empty = false;
        }
    }
}
if (!empty) {
    count++;
}
return count;
```

Once you reach the end of the method, use `empty` to decide if line count should be incremented or not. This will cover situations when your file has more than one line.

Comment: why not just start count with 1 ?

Comment: @StackFlowed Because this would double-count the last line if it does have `'\n'` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
int lines = 0;
while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
reader.close();
```